# Are there any alternatives to tracert command in cmd/PowerShell that doesn't suffer the request timed out issue?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, tcp, traceroute

The cmd `tracert <URL>` command, quite often, suffers the `request timed out` issue if the ICMP packets/port are blocked by the routers/ISP's firewall. Now I was wondering if there is any cmd/PowerShell alternative command-line tool that can traceroute using TCP or UDP protocols and measure the latency of a specific web service?

Comment: `tracert` doesn't measure latency of web services, it measures latency of hops along a path to a host. Please clarify if you want to know about `tracert` or web services. Also, UDP latency measurements need to be protocol aware because it's a connection less protocol.

Comment: @mtak I'm clearly not well educated about the topic and I might be misusing the terminology. What I want to know is why a specific service I use (i.e.,  a URL) is so slow, and where the bottleneck is along the path.

Comment: That's fine, that's why we ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If `tracert` takes too much time timeout, you could reduce this wait
by using its `-w milliseconds` parameter.
Another quick connectivity test method is by using `telnet`.

To use TCP, use the tracetcp free project:

- Download and install the [WinPcap library](https://www.winpcap.org/)
- Download the latest release of
  [tracetcp](https://simulatedsimian.github.io/tracetcp.html)
- Extract the archive to use.

Command syntax:

```
tracetcp.exe hostname:port
```

Example:

```
tracetcp.exe api.opendns.com:443
```

Comment: sadly both `telnet` and `tracetcp` clients require software download and/or admin privileges that I do not have. 

Comment: Unfortunately you are stuck with the built-in utilities of Windows.